# Create VSCode extension where add custom data for yaml files

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscode-extensions

I would like to create a VSCode extension where to display information when i do mouse hover over the word in YAML files. Like in the example https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-custom-data/tree/main/samples/helloworld. Here it is only for HTML and CSS file but I couldn't find any examples for YAML files.

Comment: Make a `HoverProvider` (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#HoverProvider) and then get back to us with any issues.